# Can it be explained; the difference in array behavior between the use of array=$( command ) and array=( $( command ) )?

Tags: bash, array, command-substitution, subshell

I understand command substitution. I understand subshells.  I do not understand why using a subshell changes the structure of my array.

Given this command output:
(use of openstack command is not intended to be relevant)

```
bash$ floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value
172.25.250.106
172.25.250.107
172.25.250.101
```

Attempt to capture in an array, but all addresses end up in element 0:

```
bash$ float=$( openstack floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value )
bash$ echo ${float[@]}
172.25.250.106 172.25.250.107 172.25.250.101
bash$ echo ${#float[@]}
1
bash$ echo ${float[0]}
172.25.250.106 172.25.250.107 172.25.250.101
bash$ echo ${#float[0]}
44
```

The whole output was captured as a string and not parsed into elements.  I was expecting each word to become an element.  When I repeat this to ensure that each IP address is quoted (using -f csv instead of -f value), the results are the same.

Next, I put the command substitution in a subshell:

```
bash$ unset float
bash$ float=( $( openstack floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value ) )
bash$ echo ${float[@]}
172.25.250.106 172.25.250.107 172.25.250.101
bash$ echo ${#float[@]}
3
echo ${float[0]}
172.25.250.106
echo ${#float[0]}
14
```

This was the behavior I expected originally.  I also notice that building the array using a read statement worked as expected:

```
bash$ unset float
bash$ read -a float <<< $( openstack floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value )
bash$ echo ${float[@]}
172.25.250.106 172.25.250.107 172.25.250.101
bash$ echo ${#float[@]}
3
echo ${float[0]}
172.25.250.106
echo ${#float[0]}
14
```

I would like to see the original command substitution work.  Wondering if I should have set a field separator first or what else I am missing.  I am trying to understand what causes the difference in behavior.

Comment: `float=$( ...)` is command substitution, not an array at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand the $( ... ) is command substitution.  I am trying to understand why capturing the output of that command substitution does not capture the distnct words in the string as elements.  But place the same command substitution in a subshell, and it does.

Comment: Because it's a string, not an array. You know how to make an array. I'm not really sure what the question is here.

Comment: The question is: why does placing that same command substitution inside of a subshell cause the output string to be parsed into elements when it did not when it was not placed into a subshell?  If I knew better what causes the difference in behavior, I would ask a better question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float=$( openstack floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value )
```

This creates a *string* variable, not an array variable. The string is the output of the command, minus any trailing newline.

If you attempt to use a string variable as an array, it's treated as a single-element array with the string value at position 0.

```
float=( $( openstack floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value ) )
```

This does not “put the command substitution in a subshell”. The command substitution itself `$(…)` creates a subshell. The parentheses around it do not create another subshell: they create an array. The array content it the list of words resulting from taking the output of the command, removing trailing newlines, splitting into a list of whitespace-separated words, and replacing any element of this list that contains wildcard characters that match one or more files by the list of matching file names.

Parentheses create a subshell when they're at a location where a command is expected. In `var=(…)`, what is expected immediately after the equal sign is not a command, but a value for assignment. In this context, the parentheses indicate that the value is an array.

Comment: Thank you, also.  Very helpful.  There was my confusion, misinterpreting that the parantheses are an array evaluation, not another subshell.  I can now create results with this.

Comment: In a script the right syntax would be `declare -a float=( $( openstack ... )` but as you see, it works anyway.

Comment: @hschou Using declare isn't “more right” than not using `declare`. In a function, `declare` makes the variable local. Outside of a function, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

```
float=$( openstack floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value )
```

This is [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) inside a [regular variable assignment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_23), not an array assignment. [All compound array assignments have the form `x=( ... )`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays), as you used below. There is no subshell here (other than briefly as the execution context of the substituted command).

When you use a command substitution it behaves in the same way as a variable with those contents would in that position, and so analogously with `float=$x` here, but also with `ls $x` or `foo=($x)`. [Word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) is performed on the result of the expansion, which separates the value into separate arguments at any character in the `IFS` variable.

You can suppress word splitting by quoting the expansion `"$(...)"`.

If you want to create an array of split words, you need **both** to create an array and to get the words split: that means an array assignment `foo=(...)` and a parameter or command substitution `$...` combined, as in your second case:

```
float=( $( openstack floating ip list -c 'Floating IP Address' -f value ) )
```

The `float=(...)` makes an array, and the elements come from the word-splitting performed during the command substitution `$(...)`.

---

What may be confusing is that Bash automatically converts non-arrays into singleton arrays when you use them as one, so it looks like you did get an array, but of a single item.

```
echo ${float[0]}
echo ${#float[@]}
```

This is [very subtly documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

> Any reference to a variable using a valid subscript is legal, and bash will create an array if necessary.

You'll see that more clearly if you use another index:

```
float[1]=abc
echo ${#float[@]} # => 2
```

The conversion process just uses the existing value of the variable, if any, as the item at index 0 in the array.

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis in `var=( some things )` don't mark a subshell, they're part of the [array assignment syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html). So, without them, you're assigning to a regular (scalar) variable. The right-hand side of a regular assignment doesn't go through word splitting, so `var=$(echo foo bar)` will put the string `foo bar` in `var`, with the spaces. On the other hand, the array assignment takes multiple words, so both `arr=(foo bar)` and `arr=( $(echo foo bar) )` give a two-element array.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the missing piece, that the outer parenthesis only signify array assignment and not a subshell.  Now it makes sense.